# What's wrong with passing a react functional component to .map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say that I have a component, `Todo`. It takes props `title` and `dueDate`. In a container component, I might map over some `todo`s like this:

```js
todos = [
  { title: "Read a book", dueDate: new Date() }
  // etc...
]

// ... later in the code ...

todos.map(x => <Todo title={x.title} dueDate={x.dueDate} />)
```

But, surely I could also just do this:

```js
todos.map(Todo)
```

for the same result?

I haven't seen this in any tutorials or anything so I'm wondering what's wrong with this approach instead of the verbose alternative.

Comment: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component

Comment: It won't work at all if `Todo` is a class-based component. You could simplify to `x => <Todo {...x} />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, surely I could also just do this:
>
> ```
> todos.map(Todo)
> ```

No, those are two different things. `.map(x => <Todo title={x.title} dueDate={x.dueDate}/>)` calls `React.createElement` to create the `Todo`, but just `.map(Todo)` simply calls `Todo` directly.

You need to create the element, not just call the function. Those are fundamentally different things. `<Todo ... />` doesn't call `Todo` at all, it just calls `React.createElement`, which will remember the `Todo` function and call it as/when necessary. This doesn't call `Todo`, for instance:

```
// Doesn't call `Todo`, just remembers it
const el = <Todo title={x.title} dueDate={x.dueDate}/>;
```

Later, if we use `el` in another component or with `ReactDOM.render` or similar, *then* `Todo` will be called as necessary.

> ...instead of the verbose alternative.

If you're looking for something more concise, [as jonrsharpe pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65884157/whats-wrong-with-passing-a-react-functional-component-to-map/65884241#comment116487311_65884157), you can do `.map(x => <Todo {...x}/>)`

Comment: Worth nothing, too, that this fundamentally changes how React treats them. Called as a function, it is "part of" the parent component.  Called as a component it is treated separately.  When called as a function, this can cause various issues including conditionally-called hooks that you thought were correctly placed on the  top-level of a component.

Comment: @tmdesigned - It's not so much how *React* treats them, it's just...the one calls the function, the other creates a React element. They're fundamentally different operations.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think that was the source of my confusion. Calling the functional component and creating a react element are two different things.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair, but I was suggesting noting why it matters. The end effect isn't obvious to someone like the OP, who saw the two as the same, i.e. not knowing that React does not treat it "as a function" when in the form of <Foo />.

Comment: @OriMarash - And fair enough. :-) The often-repeated statement "functional components are just functions" is true, but...it can easily lead you astray. :-)

Comment: @tmdesigned - I've clarified (I hope). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, and I really like your "just remembers it" way of explaining it.